# What are best parameters to run ImageMagick to convert low quality pdf to images (for OCR)

Tags: linux, pdf, image-processing, imagemagick, ghostscript

I have several low quality pdfs. I would like to use OCR -- to be more precise [Ocropus](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/)  to get text from them. To do use, I use first [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php)  -- a command line tool to convert pdf to images -- to transforms these pdfs into jpg or png.

However ImageMagick produces very low quality images and Ocropus hardly recognizes anything. I would like to learn what are the best parameters for handling low quality pdfs to provide as-good-as-possible-quality images to OCR.

I have found [this page](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php), but I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can learn about the detailed settings ImageMagick's "delegates" (external programs IM uses, such as Ghostscript) by typing

```
convert -list delegate
```

(On my system that's a list of 32 different commands.) Now to see which commands are used to convert to PNG, use this:

```
convert -list delegate | findstr /i png
```

Ok, this was for Windows. You didn't say which OS you use. **[*]** If you are on Linux, try this:

```
convert -list delegate | grep -i png
```

You'll discover that IM does produce PNG only from PS or EPS input. So how does IM get (E)PS from your PDF? Easy:

```
convert -list delegate | findstr /i PDF
convert -list delegate | grep -i PDF
```

Ah! It uses Ghostscript to make a PDF => PS conversion, then uses Ghostscript again to make a PS => PNG conversion. Works, but isn't the most efficient way **if you know that Ghostscript can do PDF => PNG in *one* go. And faster. And in much better quality.**

About IM's handling of PDF conversion to images via the Ghostscript delegate you should know two things first and foremost:

1. By default, if you don't give an extra parameter, Ghostscript will output images with a 72dpi resolution. That's why Karl's answer suggested to add `-density 600` which tells Ghostscript to use a 600 dpi resolution for its image output.
2. The detour of IM to call Ghostscript twice to convert first `PDF => PS` and then `PS => PNG` is a real blunder. Because you ***never*** win and harldy keep quality in the first step, but very often loose some. Reasons:

   - PDF can handle transparencies, which PostScript can not.
   - PDF can embed TrueType fonts, which Ghostscript can not. etc.pp. 
     Conversion in the direction `PS => PDF` is not that critical....)

That's why I'd suggest you convert your PDFs in one go to PNG (or JPEG) using Ghostscript directly. And use the [most recent version 8.71](http://www.ghostscript.com/releases/) (soon to be released: 9.01) of Ghostscript! Here are example commands:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
  -sDEVICE=pngalpha ^
  -o output/page_%03d.png ^
  -r600 ^
  d:/path/to/your/input.pdf
```

(This is the commandline for Windows. On Linux, use `gs` instead of `gswin32c.exe`, and `\` instead of `^`.) This command expects to find an `output` subdirectory where it will store a separate file for each PDF page. To produce JPEGs of good quality, try

```
gs \
  -sDEVICE=jpeg \
  -o output/page_%03d.jpeg \
  -r600 \
  -dJPEGQ=95 \
  /path/to/your/input.pdf
```

(Linux command version). This direct conversion avoids the intermediate PostScript format, which may have lost your TrueType font and transparency object's information that were in the original PDF file.

---

**[*]** D'oh! I missed to see your "linux" tag at first...

Answer (score 6):

`-density 600` or so should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

At least two other tools you may want to consider:

- `pdfimages`, which comes with the package `poppler-utils`, makes it easy to extract the images from a PDF without degrading them.
- `pdfsandwich`, which can give you an OCR'd file by simply running `pdfsandwich inputfile.pdf`. You may need to tweak the options to get a decent result. See [the official page](http://www.tobias-elze.de/pdfsandwich/) for more info.