# check for ghostscript support in php imagick?

Tags: php, pdf, ghostscript, imagick

is it possible to check the php imagick extension for ghostscript support?

for example if it is turned on / off, the ghostscript version used, etc.

which possibilities are there to get additional ghostscript / pdf details?

the only thing i've found so far is this (version of imagick lib itself):

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getversion.php

ps: no system calls are allowed (e.g. exec) from within php

Comment: found this just now: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.queryformats.php - it only lists the supported formats. better than nothing, but is there a way to get more information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know much about `imagick`, but some things about `imagemagick`. My guess is that by reading [**this answer related to imagemagick**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3613720/359307) could help you with imagick as well:

```
 convert -list delegate | grep -Ei '(PDF|PS|EPS)'
```

(`convert` is one of the CLI utilities which are part of `imagemagick`.)

Comment: that's the problem: i can't use the command line or other external software as the script needs to run in php and without any system-calls via exec() or system(). the queryFormats method i've found and mentioned above is my only straw at this moment and it can accept a parameter where \*PDF\* lists all pdf extensions that are supported. thanks anyway :)